# Easily output the hstore format of a table row

Tags: postgresql, hstore

Is there a better way to get a row of a table into hstore format than going

```
SELECT hstore(ARRAY['col1','col2','col3'], ARRAY[col1::text, col2::text, col3::text]) FROM tbl;
```

It works, but I figure there has to be a better way than typing out each column. hstore takes a record type for input, but I couldn't figure out how to feed the single-row producing query into the function and make it happy. Postgres version 9.0.4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes - you can cast row to hstore type with `hstore()` function.

```
SELECT hstore(tbl.*) FROM tbl;
```

Works for me:

```
filip@filip=# select hstore(foo.*) from foo;
         hstore
------------------------
 "bar"=>"1", "baz"=>"2"
(1 row)
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE

Comment: Ah! I didn't think to put the table name in there. I just tried SELECT hstore(*) FROM tbl. Thanks!

Comment: From some reason asterisk alone `(*)` is parsed in different way than `(foo.*)`. Strange but that's how it works.